# What username & password should be entered to use SQL plus

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am using oracle 12c sometimes I need to use SQL plus.
When I start sqlplus, it ask me for a username and password
[image]

I used SYSTEM and SYS as users but don't work with me .Anybody has a solution please

Comment: How do you usually connect to your DB? Use the same user and the same password

Comment: @Aleksej I use users like SYS and SYSTEM don't work with me

Comment: Try open sqlpuls with /nolog option then try to connect with something like: `connect sys/YOURPASSWORD@YOURDB as sysdba` or `connect sys/YOURPASSWORD@YOURDB as sysoper`

Comment: when you open it at first time it ask you to enter the user and password after you can connect with nolog @Aleksej

Comment: I put an answer with a sequence of commands that connect, change connection, and so on, starting from a cmd prompt; try to check what part of the answer works / not works

Answer (score 6):

Since you are on 12c, if you do not mention the **Pluggable database**, by default you will connect to the **Container database** i.e. `CDB$ROOT`. You need to explicitly mention whether you want to connect to the **CDB** or the **PDB**.

Read **[Oracle 12c Post Installation Mandatory Steps](https://lalitkumarb.com/2014/10/01/mandatory-steps-for-12c-installation/)**

See,

```
C:>sqlplus

SQL*Plus: Release 12.1.0.1.0 Production on Wed Feb 3 16:41:44 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: system
Enter password:
Last Successful login time: Wed Feb 03 2016 16:39:42 +05:30

Connected to:
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.1.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Advanced Analytics and Real Application Testing opt
ions

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------
CDB$ROOT
```

`CDB$ROOT` which means I am connected to **CDB**.

Let's connect to the **PDB**:

```
SQL> alter session set container=pdborcl;

Session altered.

SQL> show con_name

CON_NAME
------------------
PDBORCL
```

You should tell Oracle whether you need to connect to CDB or PDB:

```
sqlplus username/password@service_name
```

Comment: My admin has set password=Admin@123, how can I connect to it as @ begins service name

Comment: @MaulikModi Like this `sqlplus user/"Admin@123\!"@service`

Answer (score 5):

Use this command in terminal or cmd 
sqlplus /nolog.
This is mentioned in Oracle Database Administrator’s Guide

> Start SQL*Plus and connect to your Oracle Database instance with the SYSDBA system
>   privilege. To authenticate with a password file, enter the following commands, and then
>   enter the SYS password when prompted:
>
> - $ sqlplus /nolog
> - SQL> CONNECT SYS AS SYSDBA

This should help!

Comment: the second command is asking for password . What shall i provide ?

Answer (score 4):

As an example, a sequence of operations about connecting to Oracle with SQLPlus;
starting from a CMD prompt, I have the following:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versione 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation. Tutti i diritti riservati.
D:\>tnsping xe

TNS Ping Utility for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 03-FEB-2016 20:02:46

Copyright (c) 1997, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Used parameter files:
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\admin\sqlnet.ora


Used TNSNAMES adapter to resolve the alias
Attempting to contact (DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 127.0.0.1)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER
 = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = XE)))
OK (20 msec)

D:\>sqlplus /nolog

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Mer Feb 3 20:02:52 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

SQL> conn sys/Passw0rd@xe as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> conn sys/Passw0rd@xe as sysoper
Connected.
SQL> conn system/Passw0rd@xe
Connected.
SQL>
```

I hope this may help to understand what works / not works for you, thus helping everyone to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I Install SQL Developer 19c on my Mac recently and when I try to log in SQL Plus I use:

username: system

password: oracle

and it works just fine. Hope it helps